# Camel Read File Content

Tags: java, file, apache-camel

Is there a way(api function) to read the whole content of a file(or line by line) in camel without writing a converter or any java code?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean. Please rephrase your question and provide more detail where and how you want to read the content of a whole file

Comment: it was so clear actually. I am new in using camel. So I could not find a code sample that reads the content of a file , and I found it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found it, Sorry guys for bothering:

```
from("file://inputdir/").convertBodyTo(String.class)
```

Comment: You don't know how much this single line helped. Thanks!